# Call function once from multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I've been working on webpages for a range of touch screen devices, and one of the most consistent problems is how touch events are handled.

Is there a nice way to only call a function once even when multiple (roughly) simultaneous events call it?

e.g.

```
$("body").on("mousedown touchstart MSPointerDown", function () {
    alert("This message will appear multiple times on some devices.");    
})
```

I've thought about using a timeout so the function can only be called once every 200 milliseconds or something similar (off the top of my head and untested):

```
var allowed = true;
$("body").on("mousedown touchstart MSPointerDown", function () {
    if(allowed){
        allowed = false;
        alert("This message will hopefully only appear once!");
        setTimeout(function () { allowed = true }, 200);
    }
})
```

(For this question, I am NOT looking for plugin suggestions, I am aware there are lots of touch event plugins)

Is there a proper/nicer way to use multiple events as possible triggers for a single function? Could I alias the events in some way without breaking their other uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In effect, you're looking to take only the first event **type** that comes through and ignore all the others. This will still fire for future clicks/touches. Enter [closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function alertClosure() {
    var eventType = null;

    function doAlert(e) {
      if (!eventType) {
        eventType = e.type; // only the first eventType we get will be registered
      }

      if (e.type == eventType) {
        alert("This message will hopefully only appear once!: " + e.type);
      }
    }

    return doAlert;
  }

  $("body").on( "mousedown touchstart MSPointerDown", alertClosure() );
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/oz48d3

Answer (score 0):

You could use $.one (rather than $.on)

Here : [$.one documentation on jquery.com](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

If you want it to be subsequently called then you could rebind the handler on a timeout, something like this:

```
function handler(){
var called = false;
return function(ev){
    if(!called){
        called = true;
        $("ul#messages").append($("<li>").text("event"));
        setTimeout(bind, 1000); // rebind after a suitable pause
    }
}
}

function bind(){
    $("ul#messages").one("click", new handler())        
};

$(function(){
    bind();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p3t6xo48/5/

This allows each bound handler to be run once, and once only, for multiple events, then it's rebound after a suitable pause.

Comment: Unfortunately I want to be able to do these things multiple times, just not have multiple events call it each time. e.g. One tap = one alert, then you can tap again for another.

Comment: Ah!  just edited to include this scenario - have a look, let me know what you think

Comment: A nice idea, but having had a look at the .one() function, it seems it will execute "once for each event type." Which is precisely what I'm attempting to avoid. So we're falling back to the setTimeout I originally mentioned just in an alternative layout.

Comment: Shame - just added a jsfiddle - worth having a poke on the touchscreen - see if that doesn't actually shake out in the end.

Comment: Just updated the js fiddle to use a singleton pattern - the bind call now uses a new handler(), rather than just handler) - suspect this might do it.

Comment: DBS - apologies - didn't update the url for the fiddle - it's correct now.  Seems to work ok.  can you confirm?